# Multiselect Dependent Field Custom Module

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, edit, fieldsets, dependent-fields

I have two Multi select Drop downs admin. i tried to make it dependent but not success.

Below is code :-

Multiselect 1:-

```
 $fieldset->addField('mainfiled_id', 'multiselect', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('Custom')->__('custom main field'),
            'class' => 'required-entry',
            'required' => true,
            'name' => 'location_id',
            'values' => Mage::getSingleton('custom/userlocation')->getOptionArray(),
        ));
```

Multiselect 2:-

```
$fieldset->addField('dependent_ids', 'multiselect', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('custom')->__('Dependent'),
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
        'name' => 'pos_ids',
        'values' => Mage::getSingleton('custom/dependent')->getOptionArray(),
    ));
```

On based selection of Multiselect 1 need to update values of Multiselect 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage to work this by use the concept of following code. I have added a code snippet which is for dropdowns. You need to change those according to your requirement.

```
$field = $fieldset->addField('dropdown', 'select', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('module1')->__('Dropdown'),
    'values'   => Vendor_Module1_Block_Adminhtml_Custom_Grid::getValueArray1(),
    'name' => 'dropdown',                   
    "class" => "required-entry",
    'onchange' => 'change(this.value)',
    "required" => true,
));             

$field->setAfterElementHtml("<script>
function change(selectItem){
    alert(selectItem);
    var reloadurl =  '". $this->getUrl('*/*/actionurl')."';

    new Ajax.Request(reloadurl, {
        method: 'get',
        parameters: {selectItem: selectItem},
        onSuccess: function(selectElement) {
        var results = JSON.parse(selectElement.responseText);

        if(typeof results.error != 'undefined') {
            document.getElementById('dropdown1').innerHTML = results.error;
            return;
        }

        document.getElementById('dropdown1').innerHTML = results.image;
        }
    });
}
</script>");

$fieldset->addField('dropdown1', 'select', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('module1')->__('Dropdown1'),
    'values'   => Vendor_Module1_Block_Adminhtml_Custom_Grid::getValueArray2(),
    'name' => 'dropdown1',
));
```

Here you need to create one controller action from where you need to return proper options html. Rest will be done by javascript. This is just a basic idea to use dependency fields in magento admin forms.

***Note: Code was not tested.***